# How to just switch to the perticular tab in TabLayOut in android with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have 5 tabs in my TabLayOut in Android. Whenever iam switching from 1st tab to the 5th tab, the ViewPager is showing Tab2,Tab3,tab4 and then switching to tab5. How can i switch off this behavior. When i click on Tab5, it shd directly display the Tab5

Comment: can u post any code as well, adapter?

Comment: got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the animation by including false as the second parameter of `setCurrentItem()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, but i need the smooth transition effect, but only from tab1 to Tab5, i dont want to see the middle tabs on the screen white transition, is it not possible?